# Is the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\alpha = 2\pi i /3$, a splitting extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Is the extension $\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}:\mathbb{Q}$ where $\alpha=e^{{2\pi i}/3}$ splitting extension because it has degree 2?

Comment: What do you mean by a splitting extension?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by splitting extension. The extension is normal, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of some polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. (here it is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$).

Comment: @Mark my mistake, there must be splittig field

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by "splitting extension" you mean "normal extension", as in "the splitting field of some polynomial". As the extension $\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q$ has degree $2$, it must necessarily be the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (which is $x^2 + x + 1$). So the answer is yes.