# Dihedral and permutation groups isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, permutations, galois-theory, group-isomorphism

Why dihedral group $\mathbb{D_4}$ is isomorphic with   $\mathbb{S_4}$ and not isomorphic with  $\mathbb{S_8}$?

Comment: Just to comment that if $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$ (naming conventions differ occasionally) it is realised as the group  of symmetries of a regular $n-$gon. This group acts faithfully on the $n$ vertices of the $n-$gon and this action gives an isomorphism with a subgroup of $S_n$. If $m\gt n$ we can choose $n$ of the $m$ points permuted by $S_m$ and find an isomorphism with a subgroup of $S_m$

Comment: This is your second question on this today. Both have just stated a question, which isn't particularly helpful (why do you think this is the case? What have you tried to show that it is true/false?). You need to apply the advice given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3224307/10513) closed question of yours: "provide additional context...(including) source, possible strategies, your current progress."

Comment: That is: where did you find this question? What have you tried?!

Answer (score 3):

It's not isomorphic. $\Bbb D_4$ has $8$ elements (according to one convention; according to the other convention it has $4$ elements), while $\Bbb S_4$ has $24$ elemnents.

On the other hand, $\Bbb D_4$ is in a natural way isomorphic to a *subgroup* of $\Bbb S_4$, because they are both groups of symmetries on a set of $4$ elements.

Of course, a group of symmetries on $4$ elements can be seen as acting on $8$ elements, except it doesn't do anything to the last $4$ (or it does the same thing to the last $4$ as it does to the first $4$, in some variation), so both $\Bbb D_4$ and $\Bbb S_4$ are isomorphic to subgroups of $\Bbb S_8$ in this manner.

However, $\Bbb D_4$ is also isomorphic to a subgroup of $\Bbb S_8$ in a different way: There are $8$ elements in $\Bbb D_8$, and each element on $\Bbb D_8$ permutes the elements in $\Bbb D_8$ by multiplication (say from the left). In other words, $a\in \Bbb D_8$ is a permutation $\Bbb D_8\to\Bbb D_8$ defined by $a(b) = ab$. This makes it a subgroup of $\Bbb S_8$ in a different way to the way described above.

Comment: Ok thanks. But is exist subgroup of $\mathbb{S_8}$ which is isomorphic  $\mathbb{D_4}$ or not? @Arthur

Comment: @Bambeil Se updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a non-standard definition of $\Bbb D_4,$ it isn't isomorphic to either of them. $\Bbb D_4$ has either $4$ or $2\cdot 4=8$ elements, depending on your definition, while $\Bbb S_4$ has $4!=24$ elements, and $\Bbb S_8$ has $8!=40320$ elements.

The dihedral group $\Bbb D_3$ happens to be isomorphic to $\Bbb S_3,$ but that's an exceptional case.